# Show that $X$ is a basis of the free vector space $F(X)$, where $X$ is a set.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

Consider a set $X$ and a field $F$, we can construct a free vector space canonically as:

$$F(X):=\left\{\sum_{k \in F} k_x x\,:\, k_x=0\, \text{except for a finite number of}\, x \in X\right\}.....(1)$$

where the operations "sum" and "scalar multiplication" can be also defined canonnically, and I have no doubt this is a vector space over $F$. Nonetheless, my question is about proving $X$ is a basis for this vector space $F(X)$. A lot of proofs I have checked regarding this, claim that $F(X)$ can be thinked as

$$F(X):= \left\{ f: X \to F \,:\, f(x) \neq 0 \, \text{ for a finite number of}\, x \in Dom(f)   \right\}.....(2)$$

So my first question is how this two definitions of $F(X)$ are equal??? Then for $F(X)$ as defined in (2)  we can define for each $x \in X$, a function $\delta_{x}: X \to F$ as $$\delta_{x}(y)=
\begin {cases}
1 \in F \quad \text {if} \quad y = x, \\
0 \in F\quad \text {if} \quad x \neq  y.
\end {cases}$$.

It is clear that for each $x \in X$, $\delta_{x} \in F(X)$ as defined in (2) f. An there is way to prove that the set $ \lbrace \delta_{x} \rbrace_{x \in X}$ is a basis for $F(X)$ regarded as (2). But im wondering if it is true that $X = \lbrace \delta_{x} \rbrace_{x \in X}$?? and if so how can I show that?

Comment: Well, what does $\sum_{k \in F} k_x x$ even mean?  Your definition of $F(X)$ is not complete until you define what this symbol means.  The standard choice is to say that *by definition* it refers to the function $f:X\to F$ defined by $f(x)=k_x$.

Comment: Suppose $X= \lbrace a, b, c \rbrace$ then a member of $F(X)$ as established in (1), can be $0(a)+k(b)+k''(c)$ where $k, k'' \in F$.  @EricWofsey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(2)$ is the correct definition of $F(X)$. It is a rigorous definition. But it might get annoying to work with functions all the time, so we want an easier notation. So if $f\in F(X)$ is a function which satisfies $f(x)=k_x$ for all $x\in X$ then we denote it like a formal sum:

$f=\sum_{x\in X}k_xx$

This is just a **notation**, nothing more. And now note that if we take $f=\delta_x$ then we have $k_x=1$ and $k_y=0$ for all $y\ne x$. So by our notation:

$\delta_x=\sum_{y\in X}k_yy=1x=x$

And so we identify $\delta_x$ with the element $x$, and under this identification we can say that $X$ is a basis of $F(X)$. But formally, $\{\delta_x\}_{x\in X}$ is the basis, not the set $X$ itself.

Comment: Thanks!!! This was very insightful mainly because you take the time to write and explain the details. Now I see that for $X= \lbrace a, b \rbrace$ )to keep it simple) and $f \in F(X)$ as (2), the sum  $f=k_{a}a +k_{b}b$ is just another notation for the usually notation $f= \lbrace (a,k_{a}) , (b,k_{b}) \rbrace$  right ?

Comment: Well, $\sum_{x \in X} k_xx$ is not entirely just a notation for a function, it is actually the function $\sum_{x \in X} k_x\delta_x$ (for $f,g \in F(X)$ and $\lambda \in F$, we define $\lambda f+g$ to be the function $X \to F ;\, x \mapsto \lambda f(x)+g(x)$).

Comment: @Sok Yes, this is correct.

Comment: @azif00 Thing is, $f=\sum_{x\in X} k_x\delta_x$ is a true equality of functions. On the other hand $\sum_{x\in X} k_xx$ is a notation. (where we write $x$ instead of $\delta_x$. It's like we use formal sums instead of actual functions). So it is a good notation because it respects the vector space operations.

Comment: I agree, I just wanted to emphasize that the sigma notation for such function has a justification.

Comment: As an aside, (2) isn't quite the right definition if we're working without the law of excluded middle and $X$ is a set with undecidable equality. For instance, consider $F(\mathbb{R})$, and assume Brouwer's principle that all functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous. Then it turns out that according to definition (2), $F(\mathbb{R}) \simeq 0$, since $f \in F(\mathbb{R})$ can only be nonzero for a finite number of $x$ values and must be continuous, hence must be zero.